# Iterator to generate all the words (of a given words) that are one change away

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, iterator, iteration

I'm trying to create an iterator, that will generate all the words that are one change away.

For example, if my input is "sam", I should get the following words:

"aam", "bam", ..."ram","tam",...."zam","sbm","scm",..."szm","saa","sab",..."san","sao",..."saz".

Notice that there is no "sam" in the output, as it is 0 changes away.

The following function, it(), is a simple function that does this and prints the output:

```
public class oneChangeAway implements Iterator {
String s;

oneChangeAway(String s)
{
    this.s =s;
}
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
      return false;
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void remove() {

}

public void it() {
    int len = s.length();
    String temp ;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char[] char_s = s.toCharArray();
        for(char c= 'a'; c<='z'; c++)
        {
            char_s[i] = c;
            temp = new String(char_s);
            if ( temp.equals(s)) continue;
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, now I want an iterator to do this. This is what I came up with:

```
public class oneChangeAway implements Iterator {
String s;

int l;
int i ;
char c ;
char[] c_s;
oneChangeAway(String s)
{
    this.s =s;
    l =s.length();
    i = 0;
    c = 'a';
    c_s = s.toCharArray();
}
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if ( i == l)
    return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    String temp;
    if ( this.hasNext())
    {
        c_s[i] = c;
        c++;
        temp = new String(c_s);
        if( c == ('z' + 1))
        {
            c = 'a';
            c_s[i] = s.toCharArray()[i];
            i++;
        }
        if (temp.equals(s)) return this.next();
        return temp;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void remove() {

}

public void it() {
    int len = s.length();
    String temp ;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char[] char_s = s.toCharArray();
        for(char c= 'a'; c<='z'; c++)
        {
            char_s[i] = c;
            temp = new String(char_s);
            if ( temp.equals(s)) continue;
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The following main function calls it:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String args[])
{

    oneChangeAway ia = new oneChangeAway("sam");

    //ia.it();

    while (ia.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(ia.next());
    }
}
}
```

This seems to work and the output is as intended. However, am I doing it the 'right' way?

Answer (score 4):

> am I doing it the 'right' way?

Please excuse the rude answer but: *No*.

### general critic

Java is a *class based object oriented* language. So you should solve the problem in an *object oriented* way. This does **not** nessesarrily mean that your approach needs more classes and objects, but it **does** mean that you should apply the *single responsibility pattern* and find better *separation of concerns*.

Eg.: The responsibility of an `Iterator` is to give access to individual elements of a collection or stream like data structure. But the *creation* of this elements is not.

### detailed critic

#### formal issues

**naming**

The way you choose the names in you approach has some problems.

First of all you should stick to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) In particular *class names* should always start with an *upper case* letter and the first part in a *method name* should be a *verb*.

Your variables should have readable names taken from the problem domain. You have one letter abreviations. It is quite certain that you don't remember the meaning of that one letter variables yourself when you read this in 2 month...

**magic numbers**

In your approach you use *magic numbers*, even if they are `char`s actually. You should rather use *constants* with proper names like `LETTER_WITH_LOWEST_ASCII_VALUE` instead of `'a'`.

**returning literal `null` explicitly**

You should never return a literal `null` reference explicitly unless it is a valid part of the result space.

Especially you should not indicate an error by returning `null`. Use exceptions instead. In your case the `next()` method should throw  `NoSuchElementException` instead of returning `null`.

**single line blocks**

If you omit the curly braces for *single line blocks* then at least proper indent this line.

**explicit use of literal `true`/`false`**

In your `hasNext()` method you explicitly return the literal  `true`/`false` values. This introduces the possibility to change the methods logic by accident. Why didn't you simply return the result of the compare instead of wrapping it into an `if` statement?

**use of `continue`**

`continue` and `break` are the *poor mans goto*. In 20+ years of coding in Java I never ever used a `continue` or a `break` (other than inside a `switch`  where `break` is inevitable).
So instead of placing a `continue` think of how you could write your code without it, which is very simple in your case.

**raw types**

The `Iterator` interface supports a *generics* parameter but your implementation does not use it. Therefore  your `next()` method is declared to return a `Object` and the caller of your code must explicitly cast the value to a `String` relying on you that you don't return something else.

#### broken OO principles

**separation of concerns / single responsibility**

As already mentioned the *creation* of the result collection is out of scope of an `Iterator`s responsibility.

Therefore you should have a separate class or a method in your "main app" that creates some `Collection` or a Java8-`Stream` containing the result elements. Then there would be no need to write your own `Iterator` implementation at all.

#### other missed *best practices*

**single abstraction layer**

*single abstraction layer* means that a method either calls other methods or does some "low level" operations, but not both. (only loops, and conditionals are allowed in both method types).

You method `next()` does both: it calls `hasNext()` and the does some operations to create the next element. The code inside the `if` block which does the "low level operations" should be moved to a separate method so that `hasNext()` only calls other methods.

Comment: Answering "No" is **never** rude :)

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot. One more question. So I understand that iterator is not the correct choice. What should I've used instead. In python, for example, 'yield' instead of 'return' in a function would do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should collect your results in a `Collection` type. In your case this collection does not have to have certain order and will not contain douplicates noe `null`. Therefor I'd recomment `HashSet`